# Using filter expression in QGIS Modeler

Tags: qgis, expression, qgis-modeler, filter

Is there a way to load a saved filter expression (.qqf or .json) in QGIS Modeler and use it in the Feature filter?

Comment: Is the expression always the same?

Comment: For each run of the model I'd like to use an other expression

Comment: You may use expressions as input for a model and hand it to the `select by expression` tool. Would this suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Erik for the idea to use `Select by expression`.
Here is my solution:
[image]

For "Input" I used "Vector Layer" and for "Filter" I used "Expression". Parameter for this model look like this:

[image]

Comment: Could you add information what your "Input" and "Filter" model input actually are?